# Jooq Postgresql set autocommit=false

Tags: spring, postgresql, jooq, hikaricp, autocommit

I am using Jooq in a Spring Application with a Hikari pool. The transaction management is Spring default.
I am trying to use the .stream() functionality with .fetchSize(), however I get the warning "A fetch size of x was set on a auto-commit PostgreSQL connection, which is not recommended".
Tried to disable the autocommit with:

```
final Connection connection = dslContext.configuration().connectionProvider().acquire();
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
DSL.using(connection)
   .select(USER.fields()).
   .from(USER)
   .fetchSize(1000)
   .stream()
```

But I am still getting the warning and all the results are returned.
How can I set autocommit to false?

Comment: fetch size influence the network roundtrips not the maximum results returned. Spring will already set the connection to auto commit false, if that isn't happening there is something weird in your setup

Comment: Thanks, the issue was that I was executing the query in a thread.

Comment: Great to hear you found the solution. Note you can answer your own question here as well, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. This way, perhaps, you can help someone who finds this question in the future, who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was executing the query in a thread, thus the Spring @Transactional was not applied.